# How to tell MODX wayFinder to detect the resource ID it is currently on

Tags: modx

I am new to WayFinder but I have been working with it a bit and it has worked great for me, However I need something a little more dynamic that I'm not sure how to do.

I have a set of 5 pages in my website and each page has another side menu, but each menu for all five resources will be slightly different

I need wayfinder to detect what the current ID is and then display the appropriate menu

I've tried a couple things but nothign i can get to work:

[[!If? &subject=`[[*28]]` &then=`[[Wayfinder? &startId=`27`&excludeDocs=`28,29,30,31,32,33,89`]]`]]

So I need to say if the ID is = to 28 display this menu if the ID is = to 29 display this one and so on.

I've also tried &idIs=`28` and a couple other variations but couldn't really find anything to help me out on this Does anyone else have any ideas how to make this work? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use output filters for conditional calls. Documentation for them is [here](http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/customizing-content/input-and-output-filters-%28output-modifiers%29)

You code would looks something like this:

```
[[*id:is=`28`:then=`[[Wayfinder? &startId=27&excludeDocs=28,29,30,31,32,33,89]]`:else=``]]
```

Answer (score 3):

With the solution typeset suggest, wayfinder will be called each time thereby causing uneeded loading time to your site. This will be faster because wayfinder only will be called when id = 28.

```
[[[[*id:is=`28`:then=`Wayfinder? &startId=27 &excludeDocs=28,29,30,31,32,33,89`:else=``]]]]
```

Read more on it here: http://modx.com/blog/2012/09/14/tags-as-the-result-or-how-conditionals-are-like-mosquitoes/

Answer (score 0):

If the menu needs to start from the current ID then you'd use 
    &startId=`[[*id]]`

If you want it to show all the resources in the current folder, you can use UltimateParent, so 
    &startId=`[[UltimateParent]]`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This should work. The subject is just the parameter you are comparing it against so it shouldn't contain the value.

```
[[!If?
   &subject=`[[*id]]`
   &operator=`EQ`
   &operand=`28`
   &then=`[[Wayfinder? &startId=`27` &excludeDocs=`28,29,30,31,32,33,89`]]`
]]
```